# What does star quoted labels mean in Vim manual *label*

Tags: vim

For example, in [this manual](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/vimum.html), you'll see in the beginning:

```
Table Of Contents                 *user-manual*
```

There're many star quoted text like `*user-manual*` in the whole manual. What are they? Are they anchors for hyperlink jumps?

Answer (score 3):

If you open the doc in vim with filetype `HELP`, you won't see those `*` or `|`s.

```
:h help-writing
```

and in TAGS section:

```
To define a help tag, place the name between asterisks (*tag-name*). 
The tag-name should be different from all the Vim help tag names and
ideally should begin with the name of the Vim plugin.  The tag name is
usually right aligned on a line.
```

basically, the tag makes it easier to jump to.

You can try when your cursor on a `|foo|` , and press `ctrl-]` you will jump to tag `*foo*`. To jump back to your original position, press `ctrl-t`. nice isn't it?

Comment: You may or may not see those characters depending on whether you have syntax highlighting enabled, the 'conceallevel' option, etc.